# Extracting parallax data from only two photos to help reconstruct a 3D scene

Tags: image

In terms of integrating Blender renders with existing photographs, is there a way to create a set of Blender mesh points using the parallax info between just a pair of stereo photographs?

I've gotten good at regular camera tracking with video, and also using BLAM for static images, but what I'd really like to do is take two very clear and stable stereo images and extract as many good 3D points from them as possible, without resorting to also videoing in order to reconstruct the scene.

Comment: Your question make me remind this article I saw wich somebody recreate a lightning in 3D from two picture: http://calculatedimages.blogspot.co.uk/2013/05/3d-lightning.html hope it can help

Comment: You could use external software and then import it into blender. [This](http://sourceforge.net/projects/reconststereo/) is one a quick google search brought up that doesn't look too bad.

Comment: Why not just use the BLAM add-on both separate photos and combine the 3D data? Or am I not correctly understanding what you want to do?

Comment: BLAM, being vanishing-point based, requires lines - specifically, edges of objects to share common X,Y, and Z axes. Parallax-based methods require only points.

Comment: You may be interested in learning camera mapping from blender guru aka
Andrew price's tutorial here [on the Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9r9tKX5olY)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could try point cloud reconstruction software which are free to download using Visual SFM and Meshlab. There are a few tutorials on the subject on youtube. As the question you are asking will require substantial write up, it's best to point you to some tutorials.

I learn this in 3 hours last night. However you may need more than 2 images.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=D6eqW6yk50k

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there is a way, because there is an image processing package called Hugin (available for free), with tutorials from http://hugin.sourceforge.net/ which does exactly what you want.

I have downloaded it and tried to do exactly what you wish, but I've not yet mastered Hugin. I do perceive that it might be more doable with some images than with others. I have it, I'm trying to learn it, but I have to say that for me, it's been more difficult than Blender. .

Tutorial link: http://hugin.sourceforge.net/tutorials/perspective/

Comment: Perhaps you could link to a tutorial on how to do this with hugin?

Comment: This tutorial is focused on removing perspective from the image, not creating a 3d model from it.  As hugin is for 2d stitching of panoramas, I would be very surprised if it can export 3d models.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - problem is, in my experience with Hugin (which i think is an awesome program), it is sort of the opposite of the principle i'm looking for. Put simply, Hugin really wants zero parallax info; even as little as the offset of the camera-body on a tripod gives it a hard time for any sort of foreground-background setting.