# Reconstruct 3D model from multiple 2D images

Tags: modeling, image

is there a way to convert multiple 2D image into a 3D model. In other words, does Blender provide a generic tool like SFM reconstruct a 3D model out of images of the object from multiple viewpoints ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, blender does not do this. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/8298/599.  You might want to ask around for a program which does this on [software recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: As a side note, blender uses [libmv](https://code.google.com/p/libmv/). The site lists some open source projects related to SfM.

Comment: @Sud There is another app that can do this called 123D catch, you can export the generated mesh as an .obj and use it in blender.

Comment: [Here](http://makezine.com/2013/08/21/diy-photogrammetry-open-source-alternatives-to-123d-catch/) is an article that also involves Blender (as screeny).

Comment: libmv was going to do that, but I think it has finally not done that for now http://code.google.com/p/libmv/