# resolve camera from two photographs

Tags: camera, tracking

Could be blender used for resolve camera focus and position, and reconstruct real point position in space from two static photographs?

In some blender versions it seems that camera tracking can do this job, because it can handle two images as "two frame movie", but it does not work with different focal distances. Recent blender versions, moreover it seems, need some minimal count of frames.

Comment: Short answer is No. To do motion tracking/camera solve the focal length has to be the same for all images. I don't know the minimal number of frames needed for reconstructing a scene, but I doubt two is enough. A not automatic way to do what you need is using [Blam](https://github.com/stuffmatic/blam) to determine the camera angle of the first image based on vanishing points, and then use its photo base modeling tools. Then lock the view to camera, use the second image as background and move to try and find the placement for the second picture and then refine the geometry.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40308/how-do-i-align-my-grid-to-background-footage/40330#40330

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8298/extracting-parallax-data-from-only-two-photos-to-help-reconstruct-a-3d-scene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, blender rally can't do this,
but solution for now calls fSpy:

https://fspy.io/

Standalone application with blender plugin.
Formerly known as Blam.